# Set Label content and make it disappear after 5 seconds

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

Let's say I have a label and a button. If I click the button, the label is set to some text, say "hello, world!", and after 5 seconds, it should disappear. Easy enough, right? I have the following implementation:

```
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Label = "hello, world!";
  await Task.Delay(5_000);
  Label = string.Empty;
}
```

Now let's say I have the additional requirement that the button should remain responsive on each subsequent button click, and now the label text should remain `hello, world!` for the next 5 seconds i.e. the label text should remain for 5 seconds since the last time the button was clicked. The problem with the previous code is that if I had clicked the button 2.5 seconds ago and click it again now, the label text will disappear after 2.5 seconds. My idea to solve this was to maintain a list of tasks and add the delay task and await the task list before clearing the label. This is the implementation:

```
private static readonly List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Label = "hello, world!";
  TaskList.Add(Task.Delay(5_000));      
  await Task.WhenAll(TaskList);
  if (TaskList.TrueForAll(t => t.IsCompleted))
  {
    TaskList.RemoveAll(t => t.IsCompleted);
    Label = string.Empty;
  }
}
```

As far as I know, this implementation works, but I don't know much about asynchronous programming so I don't know how to be *absolutely sure* it works.

**Questions**:
How would you implement this? Is there a better way to implement this? I originally figured that `Task.WhenAll()` would take care of waiting for all tasks to complete, but this does not seem to be the case. What am I getting wrong?

**Edit**:
Implementation with a cancellation token:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Label = "hello, world!";
  _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
  _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  try
  {
    await Task.Delay(5_000, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    Label = string.Empty;
  } catch (TaskCanceledException) { }
}
```

Comment: I believe the term you are looking for is how to throttle the event handler of the button click

Comment: @Nkosi Can you say a little more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just cancel the pending task `await Task.Delay(5_000, cancelToken);` using a [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) and start a new one right away.

Comment: I added an implementation with a cancellation token, can you comment on it? Thanks.

Comment: @asfeynman your code looks good in general but `_cancellationTokenSource`  should not be static.

Comment: Great, I'll fix that.